# How do I calculate the transaction fee on the Optimism network

Tags: transactions, fees, layer-2

I have this transaction hash

https://optimistic.etherscan.io/tx/0x9b8f0d63adb5c633baff74b642331d0015ea207134bd3f7f526a9b89d5dfae27

How did optimism calculate the 0.05c USD transaction fee

Can someone please walk me through the mathematical calculation

Here is what the docs say but I am still stuck.

https://help.optimism.io/hc/en-us/articles/4411895794715-Transaction-fees

Cheers